# How to find the changes from levenshtein string distance

Tags: r, stringr, levenshtein-distance, stringdist

Suppose I have 2 strings, and I want to find the edit distance between them using the Levenshtein method.  I can do that using the code below.  However, in the example below, all I can see is that it takes one "move" to transform `string1` into `string2`.  I would like to know which manipulations were done.  In this case `o -> p`.  Is there a way to find that?

```r
string1 <- 'hello'
string2 <- 'hellp'

stringdist::stringdist(
  string1,
  string2,
  method = 'lv'
)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827772/how-to-know-the-operations-made-to-calculate-the-levenshtein-distance-between-st) should help.

Comment: See [lingdist](https://github.com/fncokg/lingdist).